# How to disable FN+ARROW shortcut in iTerm2

Tags: terminal, iterm

Whenever I press FN+ARROW (left or right) while in iTerm2, I get the following characters:

```
~
❯ 0C0C0C0D0D0D0C0C0D0D
```

`0C` appears when I click FN+LEFT and `0D` appears for FN+RIGHT.
How to disable it?

Comment: Pressing fn+arrow-key is a key combo for one of these other keys: Page Up, Page Down, End, Start

Comment: Well, not in my case. As you can see, it gives me these weird characters. I noticed that in other programs on mac (e.g. VS Code), `FN + ARROW` works like pressing `CMD +SHOFT+ARROW` - it highlights a line word by word.